# Eloquent ORM relationship on laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I create messages system on laravel 5, but I cant get sender information on recuperation page *(such as name email...)*

I have messages table:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('messages', function(Blueprint $table){
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('destination_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('source_id')->unsigned();
            $table->string('sujet');
            $table->text('contenu');
            $table->boolean('vu')->default(0);
            $table->boolean('repondu')->default(0);
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->foreign('source_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('destination_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }
```

On the models I create add this:

Message Model:

```
class Message extends Model {

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}
```

and on User model I add this function:

```
public function message()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Message');
}
```

But when i Try to fetch user messages and want to get for example {{$message->user->name}} I get a error message that I try to get property of non-object

this is the controller to this page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well default user's key field when you're using: `return $this->belongsTo('App\User');` if a table name is like: `table_name_id` in this example will be like: `user_id`.

I see that you need relations to user table on:

```
$table->integer('destination_id')->unsigned();
$table->integer('source_id')->unsigned();
```

so the best solution will be to create two methods like:

```
class Message extends Model 
{
    public function source()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'source_id');
    }

    public function destination()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'destination_id');
    }
}
```

then you can call:

```
{{$message->source->name}}
```

and

```
{{$message->destination->name}}
```

Of corse you can name this method in other way, like: `sourceUser()` for example.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you didn't set foreign key for message model. If one user have many messages, you should add foreign key like that

```
    public function up()
        {
            Schema::create('messages', function(Blueprint $table){
                $table->increments('id');
                $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
                $table->integer('destination_id')->unsigned();
                $table->integer('source_id')->unsigned();
                $table->string('sujet');
                $table->text('contenu');
                $table->boolean('vu')->default(0);
                $table->boolean('repondu')->default(0);
                $table->timestamps();
                $table->foreign('source_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
                $table->foreign('destination_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
            });
        }
```